# Java: Calendar arithmetic not working

Tags: java, calendar

I am trying to get a person's age if I have the birthday and the current. What I do is subtract the year from the birthday year. The current year is 2014. And my sample birthday is 1960, but it returns 0 instead of 53.

```
public class Person implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7056942232246992667L;
    String fname, mname, lname, houseNum, street, city, state, country;
    ArrayList<String> schools = new ArrayList<String>();
    int age, yr, mt, dy;
    String zipCode, ssn, id;
    static Calendar bday;

    public Person(String fnamei, String mnamei, String lnamei, int yri, int mti, int  dyi, String houseNumi, String streeti, String cityi, String statei, String zipi, String countryi, String idset) {
        fname = fnamei; mname = mnamei; lname = lnamei; yr = yri; mt = mti; dy = dyi;
        houseNum = houseNumi; street = streeti;
        city = cityi; state = statei; zipCode = zipi; country = countryi;
        id = idset; age = -1;
        bday = new GregorianCalendar(yr, mt, dy);

        GregorianCalendar currDate = new GregorianCalendar();
        GregorianCalendar thisYearBDay = new GregorianCalendar(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR), mt, dy);
        int thisYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        age = thisYear - yr;
        if (currDate.before(thisYearBDay)) {
            age--;
        }
    }
    public int getAge() {
        System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)); //2014
        System.out.println(bday.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)); //1960
        return age; //0? Should be 53/54
    }
```

How person object is declared:

```
Person sample = new Person("John", "Sample", "Doe", 1960, 5, 1, "100", "Test St.", "City", "US", "10000", "US", "10000001");
```

Comment: What values are you creating the `Person` object with?

Comment: Every time I see a date-time question, I sigh, "JodaTime".

Comment: you know, if yri = 2014, then the age will be zero I think...

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: @Leo But the _yri_ isn't 2014. It's 1960.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Why does _getAge()_ return 0 instead of *2014 - 1960*?

Comment: @Nishant And what are you suggesting with _JodaTime_?

Comment: @Nishant just told a joke ;-)

Comment: Just to be sure, I copied/pasted and ran your code and guess what... it returned 53!

Comment: I think @SotiriosDelimanolis got it. I'd just like to tell Brandon to revisit his code. Is it really necessary for bday to be static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling

```
bday.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) // 1960
```

`getInstance()` is a `static` method that returns a new `Calendar` object. You can invoke `static` methods on instances, but it is highly discouraged for exactly this reason.

You're calling `get(int)` on that new instance which is initialized to today, ie. year 2014, not on the instance referenced by `bday`.

Comment: so it was 2014 :-) [but you figured why]

Answer (score 0):

I have run your example and it prints

```
2014
2014
53
```

"as expected".

The line

```
System.out.println(bday.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)); //1960
```

prints 2014 because `bday.getInstance()` creates a new instance of calendar. To print the birth year, use

```
System.out.println(bday.get(Calendar.YEAR)); //1960
```

Another proposition is to declare interface other than concrete class, for example:

```
List<String> schools = new ArrayList<String>(); 
Calendar currDate = new GregorianCalendar();
```